# How to make PHPUnit partially regenerate a code coverage HTML log

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, code-coverage, php-code-coverage

I'm using PHPUnit to generate code coverage data using the HTML logging type. Sometimes I'll generate a full coverage log across the whole codebase, and then rerun the tests with coverage on a smaller subset of the codebase from within PHPStorm.

Unfortunately, the newly generated coverage report will only show coverage for the smaller subset of the codebase, with the rest of the codebase shown at 0% coverage. The previously generated coverage information has been lost.

Is there any way to configure things so that the newly generate coverage log on the small subset of tests will be combined with the old coverage log?

Comment: Not sure, highly doubt. When you run your PHPUnit from PhpStorm with "Run with Coverage", it passes own path for coverage report file that then automatically gets added/replaced in coverage suite data to display. So even if you run partial coverage, it will replace that full run from before.

Comment: Sure, you can display coverage data from multiple sources .. but it needs to be done manually (as automatic one clears all entries and adds the one from most recent run). Check `Tools | Show Code Coverage Data` entry -- you can add your own entries there manually.

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167775/aggregating-code-coverage-from-several-executions-of-phpunit